# How to use Android studio

Tags: android, methods, overriding, android-studio-2.3

When I press "Ctrl+o" or "ctrl+I" I saw a this error "no methods to override have been found".
How can I fix it?
My androidstudio's version is 2.3.3

Comment: Is your class extending another class or implementing an interface?

Answer (score 1):

Owing to a lack of further information, this is purely a guess with regards to your problem. However, the functionality of Implement (Crtl + I) and Override (Ctrl + O) depend on if your class is implementing an interface or extending another class.

### Implement (Ctrl + I)

This will only work if your class is implementing an interface or extending a class with abstract methods e.g.

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
```

Pressing `Ctrl + I` will bring up a list of methods you have yet to implement. If you have implemented all methods then this will bring up the `"No methods to implement have been found"` error as there is nothing else to implement.

### Override (Ctrl + O)

Pressing `Ctrl + O` will bring up a list of methods from your parent class that you can change the behaviour of (i.e. override the behaviour). By default this should bring up the `public` methods of `Object` as all Java classes implicitly extend `Object` by default. I can't say why you're getting this error unless you post the class that you're trying to override in your question, my only guess is that you're extending a class with no override-able methods.

Comment: I have this IDE Fatal Errors "entry fileTemplates//code/google test fixture setup method.cc.ft not found in F:/program files/android/android studio/lib/idea.jar"

Comment: That doesn't seem like a normal error. Can you try uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio?